# I can't set a new attribute to source tag ! , so what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I can't set a new attribute to source tag ! , so what ?

```js
      $('source').attr("src", "value"); // doesn't work , why ?
```

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source id="sourc" />
</audio>
```

why it doesn't work ?

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zqdcmvgg/1/

Comment: Not working http://jsfiddle.net/frodoe7/y2yf2v60/

Comment: Not working too http://jsfiddle.net/frodoe7/y2yf2v60/1/

Comment: `<source id="sourc" />` notice the typo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y2yf2v60/3/

Comment: @user3763059 you need to add jQuery to your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't added the jquery library reference. Please include below code on head

```
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#source').attr("src" , "value"); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: no , it's already added

Comment: @user3763059 If you check your initial fiddle, **no it isn't**. You have not loaded the jQuery library. Also, you should run your JS onDOMready.

Comment: @user3763059 I think you should go through to this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_controls.asp . The "src" you are trying to set, is failed to load the file. Please try with some local audio file.

Comment: @HarshKaushal but i need to load source on server not local !

Comment: I understand, but just go through the link, also check your console, it will display the message "HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://server6.mp3quran.net/akdr/005.mp3 failed. and 
"All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused." This means it can not read the audio file from the given "src"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a different id in your code.

Add a # to the jQuery selector and make sure the selector text matches the element id.

```
 <audio controls autoplay>
       <source id="source" />
   </audio>

  $('#source').attr("src" , "value");
```

Comment: not working
http://jsfiddle.net/frodoe7/y2yf2v60/1/

Comment: @user3763059 you are not loading jquery in your fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/y2yf2v60/2/

Comment: @Cheery is correct, no library

Comment: yes working on JSFiddle , but not working in my browser !

Comment: @user3763059 the question has been marked as duplicate, the issue is not as simple (although not difficult) as what you originally asked.